# Хот-дог, жарпес чи ковбасець?

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/khotdoh) зустрів українській відповідник до слова "хот-дог" - "ковбасець". Однак, там же наткнувся на спір, чи варто взагалі перекладати дане слово. У мене ж виникають сумніви щодо такого відповідника, бо ж утворено воно було від поєднання слів "[ковбаса](http://sum.in.ua/s/kovbasa)" та "[песець](http://sum.in.ua/s/pesecj)" (не зовсім впевнений). І якщо слово "дог" ще більш-менш передано влучно, то от не зрозуміло до чого тут ковбаса, адже хот-доги не обов'язково подаються з ковбасою (сосискою), тому варіант "жарпес" виглядає набагато влучнішим, адже у ньому ще й влучно перекладено не тільки слово "дог", а ще й "хот", проте даний варіант на Словотворі не вибраний як основний.

Отож питання полягає в тому чи варто взагалі заміняти назви страв українськими відповідниками? І якщо так, то чи можна вважати "ковбасець" хорошим варіантом (враховуючи, що ця страва може взагалі бути вегатеріанською) чи все ж краще буде використати варіант "жарпес"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Як на мене, "хот-дог" - вiн i є "хот-дог". Якщо спитати будь-кого, що таке "хот-дог", — людина з великою вiрогiднiстю вiдповiсть правильно.

Ми ж не шукаємо аналогiв до слiв "бренд", "транспорт", etc.

Я так розумiю, є 3 варіанта "локалiзацii" слова:

1. Залишити як є: "хот-дог".
2. Перекласти по частинам: "жарпес".
3. Придумати щось своє: "ковбасець".

Персонально я не бачу "ковбасець" як хороший переклад, бо мало хто зрозумiє, що мова йде саме про об'єкт типу "хот-дог". "Жарпес" може бути непоганою назвою, якби, наприклад, "хот-дог" був винайдений у нас. Iнакше було б трохи дивно, якщо до нас приїздить американець, хоче купити "хот-дог", а ми його не розумiємо. I вiн не розумiє наш "жарпес". Тому персонально я голосую за "хот-дог" :)

Comment: *Ми ж не шукаємо аналогiв до слiв "бренд", "транспорт", etc.* Гм...

Comment: Слово _бренд_ відносно нове, а ось _транспорт_ [Штепа](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) вже радив як _перевіз_, шчо, по-мојему, је непогано. Сльід також зазначити, шчо мову будујемо не дльа јакогось амеріканцьа, а дльа себе.

Comment: @follower Це само собою. Але менi здається трохи нелогiчним брати вже звичнi слова iноземного походження, що вже активно використовуються - i намагатися придумати своi "локалiзацii". Хоча можу бути не правий, не виключаю

Comment: Взагалі-то це је најдоречнішоју річчьу, оскільки згодом нерідко слова набувајуть слова набувајуть свого значенньа, котре ріжнитьсьа від першоџерела. По-друге, льуди менье розуміјуть цьі слова, наприклад _транспорт_ та _бренд_ розуміјемо, бо вони на часі, але згодом вже можуть стати не на часі, јак багато вже записаних слів.

Comment: @follower Я вас трохи не зрозумiв. Який сенс мати "жарпес", якщо "хот-дог" не на часi (iх вже не продають)?

Comment: @follower Тодi за яких обставин слово "хот-дог" може стати не на часi?

Answer (score 2):

[Тлумачення СЛОВНИК.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3) та [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3)

> ***ХОТ-ДОГ***, -а, ч., кул. Сандвіч з сосискою або ковбасою; зазвичай
>   містить гірчицю та кетчуп, рідше – майонез чи подібні приправи; також
>   часто може містити в собі смажені чи свіжі овочі, зелень, сир та
>   бекон.

Вільний тлумачний словник [(Новітній онлайновий словник української мови (2013—2018)](http://sum.in.ua/f/khot-dogh)

> ***Хот-дог***, -а, чол., іноді ***хот-доґ***, -а. Гаряча сосиска покладена у
>   надрізану булочку (зазвичай із гірчицею чи іншим гарніром). //  *рідко*.
>   Окремо сосиска із цієї страви.
>
> Етимологія: англійське *hot dog*, від *hot* — гарячий, *dog* — собака.

В інших джерелах не знайшла ні хот-дог, ні жарпес. На мою думку, краще не замінювати назви страв українськими відповідниками.

Comment: ви маєте на увазі назви закордонних страв?

Comment: @AlexSodin так.